# Parse List<dynamic> using json_serializable library in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, json-serialization

Consider the following json:

```
[
 {
  "id": 1
  "name": "foo"
 },
 {
  "id": 1
  "name": "foo"
 }
]
```

I am trying to parse this using [json_serializable](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable) library.

`json.decode(response.body)` returns `List<dynamic>`.

but the json_serializable auto-generates methods `fromJson` and `toJson` with type `Map<String, dynamic json>`.

is there any way in json_serializable to parse `List<dynamic>` **with auto-generated methods and not manually**?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I would also like to do this using a factory method that generates the serializable

Answer (score 3):

you should try it this way;

```
@JsonSerializable()
class Example{
    int id; String name;
    Example({this.id, this.name})
}
```

call your Future function and save it in a variable ***{parsed}*** and then convert your mapped data to list by doing this:

```
List<Example> result = parsed.map((i) => Example.fromJson(i)).toList();
```

Comment: Why does your result have an `Example` type? It should be `List<Example>`

Comment: No you reversed the places. `List<Example> result = parsed.map((i) => Example.fromJson(i)).toList();` is correct